# Parametrising a piecewise circular curve in 3d

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves, parametrization

The curve in question is a closed curve $C: = \overline{abcda}$ made of three circular arcs $C_1=ab, C_2 =bc$, $C_3 = cd$ and a straight line segment $ C_4 = da$. The arc $C_1$ lies on a plane $P_1$ and is of radius $r$ and length $l$ while $C_3$ is also of same radius $r$ and length $l$ but lying on a plane $P_3$, where the planes $P_1$ and $P_3$ intersect along a line $q$ that is lying on another plane $P$.

The straight line segment $C_4$ is coincident with $q$ and joins the end points $a$ and $d$ of the circular arcs $C_1$ and $C_3$ respectively. Lastly the circular arc $C_2$, is of radius $R$ and length $l_0$ joining the other two end points $b$ and $c$. $C_2$ lies on a plane $P_2$ that is tangential to both the arcs $C_1$ and $C_3$ at points $b$ and $c$. There is tangent continuity at the points where the different arcs/ line segment join.The center of the circular arc $C_2$ lies on the line perpendicular to the straight line segment $C_4$ and passing through its mid-point.

To give some context, the curve was fashioned out of the 3d computer graphics design software Rhino. The congruent circular arcs $C_1$ and $C_3$ are actually curves on congruent cones on opposite sides of the tangent plane $P_2$ that contains the  circular arc $C_2$. The center of $C_2$ corresponds to an isolated tangential point of contact between the cones. See the image of the curve below without the cones. The join points are highlighted in green.

[image]

The usual way seems to use the Bezier curve approximation, but I was looking for something more classical as circular curves are not well approximated by Bezier curves and I wish to use this to parametrise a developable surface. This is probably also related to the 3d biarc concept. I understand, although this is piecewise smooth, globally it is just $C_1$. I was wondering if there is a way to parametrise the curve using the turning angles of the tangents or something more simple.

Comment: The piecewise curve is clear, but, which is the actual question?. It is clear that the straighforwards parametrization will be piecewise too...

Comment: @Brethlosze Thanks. The actual question is how to parametrise this piecewise. As this is not planar, I am a bit confused or missing something obvious.

Comment: Maybe NURBS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline

Comment: @CyclotomicField AAh. Okay. I thought this was the same as Bezier splines but turns out that is not the case and does allow for an exact respresntation of a circle unlike Bezier ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the natural parameter $s$. That is, given a piece of the curve and its point $x$, let $x=x(s)$, where $s$ is the length of the curve from the beginning of the piece to the point $x$. Then the tangent vector $x’(s)$ always has length $1$, so at points joining the pieces the tangent vectors from distinct sides are equal.

Then the segment from $d$ to $a$ of length $L$ can be parametrized as $x(s)=(1-s/L)d+(s/L)a$, $s\in [0,L]$.

Let $D$ be a circular arc of the radius $R$, length $L$, lying in the plane $Q$, with the center at the point $c$, and beginning from the point $p$. Let $n$ be a unit normal vector to the plane $Q$ at the point $c$, $m=\tfrac{1}R(p-c)$, and $k=m\times n$ be the [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). Then $D$ can be parametrized as $x(s)=c+mR\cos (s/R)+kR\sin (s/R)$, $s\in [0,L]$. Note that in general there are two circular arcs of length $L$ beginning from $p$. So if the arc chosen above has the wrong endpoint $x(L)$ then to provide the correct arc we have to switch the sign of the vector $k$ .

Comment: Thanks. I will dwell on this for a short time and get back.

Comment: The only thing confusing to me is how to tackle the points which are common to two circular arcs? The construction needs to exhibit continuity of tangents.

Comment: @Vishesh A good point. I updated the answer to provide this.

Comment: So you mean I need arc length parametrisation. I presume that to ensure a conitnuous domain, one can choose $[0,a]$ for the straight line and then $[a, a+l]$ for the next arc and son. I will need to adjust the parametrs accordingly. Am I right?

Comment: @Vishesh Yes, for each piece, we need to shift the parameter $s$ by the sum of the lengths of the previous pieces both in domains for $s$ and formulae for $x(s)$. For the segment of the length $L$ we can choose the segment $[0,L]$ (or $[-L/2, L/2]$, with more symmeric parametrization) as the domain of $s$.

Comment: Sorry one last question. So essentially we are parametrising the curve using the normal to the plane and normal to the curve i.e. in a sense the adapted frame of the curve right?

Comment: @Vishesh As I understood you, essentially yes, that is, each circular piece of the curve is essentially parametrized in the plane containing the piece, and at the beginning this parmerization is similar to the parametriztion $(\cos t,\sin t)$ of the circle $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ at the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I will accept this answer, but in case I have further questions, I hope you dont mind responding to an extra comment or two from me.

Comment: @Vishesh OK....